# Unable to POST >250MB file

Tags: python, post, request, python-requests, urllib

I'm downloading a file from a server with

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(link, 'new_vid.mp4', reporthook)
```

At the end reporthook shows me, that I downloaded 250MB of data, but at my local PC the size is 262,2MB (?)
But that's not the problem. After that I'm trying to upload the file to another server

```
files = {'video_file': (open('new_vid.mp4', 'rb'))}
response = json.loads(requests.post(upload_url, files=files).text)
```

And the response is `{'error': 'invalid_file'}`

The server mustn't block this-sized file, the limit on server is 2GB.

I suppose that the problem is somewhere around 250MB, so the file is invalid for the server because I'm posting only 250/262.2 MB?

I don't know where is the problem, would be really glad if you could help me.

Comment: If the server says "invalid file", then you need to ask the operator of that server why your file is invalid. Beyond that, all we can do here is speculate.

Comment: did you try to rename it to something more common like txt

Comment: @user3732793 well I didn't, but why would I if I need it to be .mp4? That's a videofile

Comment: @JonathonReinhart even though, why does sys.getsizeof() shows 250MB if on disk the file is 262.2?

Comment: 250MB is 262,144,000 bytes?

Comment: your files may differ on the server and on your machine because of the different filesystems. Your target server has probably rules for upload files through renaming it you could check. You could als take a smaller text file and check if it works in general

Comment: @glibdud yeah, 262,163,123... I feel like I'm getting it..

Comment: @user3732793 Didn't quite get what you mean by 'Your target server has probably rules for upload files through renaming it you could check'

Comment: @user3732793 but all of the files <250MB are easily uploaded, without any problems. With the exactly same code. And the target server doesn't have 250mb limit. So the solution is asking the server's operator, there can't be any problem on my side?

Comment: Did you try running the file to see if it's a valid mp4?

Comment: @user3732793 not mine, but again, .mp4 is allowed, 262mb file is allowed, I tested uploading .mp4 less than 250mb and everything goes fine

Comment: @glibdud yes, it is valid and running on my machine

Comment: sorry that is very odd. you could check from a friends pc if it is your connection. I still would guess it is the target server whou has something set. sorry I can't help with that

Comment: @user3732793 yeah, checked from a friend's machine and from pythonanywhere server... alright, thanks anyways